# CodeIgniter/DataMapper: reuse object

Tags: php, codeigniter-datamapper

I use this to count all active users in a database, works like it should:

```
$ouser = new User;
$data['users_active'] = $ouser->where(array('active'=>1))->count();
```

Now I also want to use the (same) object to count all *inactive* users, therefore I want to use this:

```
$ouser = new User;
$data['users_active'] = $ouser->where(array('active'=>1))->count();
$data['users_inactive'] = $ouser->where(array('active'=>0))->count();
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Clearing the object first doesn't work either:

```
$ouser = new User;
$data['users_active'] = $ouser->where(array('active'=>1))->count();
$ouser->clear();
$data['users_inactive'] = $ouser->where(array('active'=>0))->count();
```

How can I resuse the same object, in this case for counting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer can be found here (Codeigniter/Datamapper forum):
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/149388/P915/#1054666